# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAlpha(float)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an Android app. This app has 12 activities, the first activity is the Splash Screen and sec activity is the  intropage and  3rd activity is main and etc When I run the app, it doesn't enter the main activity and the app closes. The error is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAlpha(float)' on a null object reference

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAlpha(float)' on a null object reference
        at com.github.hujiaweibujidao.wava.BaseViewAnimator.reset(BaseViewAnimator.java:78)
        at com.github.hujiaweibujidao.wava.BaseViewAnimator.start(BaseViewAnimator.java:55)
        at com.github.hujiaweibujidao.wava.YoYo$Builder.start(YoYo.java:128)
        at com.github.hujiaweibujidao.wava.YoYo$Builder.playOn(YoYo.java:115)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:108)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Thank you for your answers, but the solutions you gave me did not help. I checked, but it still gave me the same error. I put three-activated codes for you. Can you help me, please?

this my main activity java code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.akshay.library.CurveBottomBar;
import com.github.hujiaweibujidao.wava.Techniques;
import com.github.hujiaweibujidao.wava.YoYo;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;
import com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.ElasticDrawer;
import com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import uk.co.samuelwall.materialtaptargetprompt.MaterialTapTargetPrompt;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CurveBottomBar cbb;
    FlowingDrawer mDrawer;
    ImageView img_icon,imgtest,img_music,img_night,img_main,img_setting;
    TextView txt;
    String patch;

    boolean read=false,music=true,night_mode;
    Button btn_fehrest,btn_last_story,btn_fav;
    SharedPreferences sharedP;
    LinearLayout lin_main;
    Toast exit;
    boolean show_intropage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cbb = findViewById(R.id.cbb);
        mDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        img_icon = findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
        imgtest = findViewById(R.id.imgtest);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        btn_fehrest = findViewById(R.id.btn_fehrest);
        img_music = findViewById(R.id.img_music);
        lin_main = findViewById(R.id.lin_main);
        img_night = findViewById(R.id.img_night);
        img_main = findViewById(R.id.img_main);
        btn_last_story = findViewById(R.id.btn_last_story);
        btn_fav = findViewById(R.id.btn_fav);
        img_setting = findViewById(R.id.img_setting);

        cbb.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_scrolling);
        sharedP = getSharedPreferences(Items.SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        show_intropage = sharedP.getBoolean(Items.INTROPAGE,true);


        cbb.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.img_setting:
                        // kary ke mikhaym anjam bedim
                        break;

                    case R.id.img_music:
                        //
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInDown).duration(1000).playOn(btn_fehrest);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInDown).duration(1000).playOn(btn_last_story);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInDown).duration(1000).playOn(btn_fav);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInDown).duration(1000).playOn(img_music);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInDown).duration(1000).playOn(img_setting);

        get_night();
        permission();
        //createFile();
        if (show_intropage){
            taptarget();
        }



        img_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mDrawer.openMenu(true);
            }
        });

        mDrawer.setTouchMode(ElasticDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_BEZEL);
        mDrawer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mDrawer.setOnDrawerStateChangeListener(new ElasticDrawer.OnDrawerStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChange(int oldState, int newState) {
                if (newState == ElasticDrawer.STATE_CLOSED) {
                    Log.i("MainActivity", "Drawer STATE_CLOSED");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(float openRatio, int offsetPixels) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "openRatio=" + openRatio + " ,offsetPixels=" + offsetPixels);
            }
        });
    }


    public void createFile(){

        try {

            patch = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Mbook/";

            File mfile = new File(patch);

            if (!mfile.exists()) {
                mfile.mkdir();
                mfile.createNewFile();
                CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("Mbook.db"), new FileOutputStream(patch+"/Mbook.db"));
                //Toast.makeText(this, patch+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void CopyDB (InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int file_length;
        while ((file_length = inputStream.read(buffer))>0){

            outputStream.write(buffer,0,file_length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public void fehrest_intent(View view) {
        mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse).duration(800).playOn(btn_fehrest);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Fehrest.class);
                intent.putExtra("button","fehrest");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        },1500);

    }

    private void permission(){

        Dexter.withContext(MainActivity.this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {

                        createFile();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                        if (response !=null && response.isPermanentlyDenied()){

                            AlertDialog.Builder Hoshdar = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            Hoshdar.setMessage("جهت استفاده از برنامه دادن اجازه دسترسی ضروریست");
                            Hoshdar.setCancelable(false);
                            Hoshdar.setPositiveButton("رفتن به تنظیمات", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package",getPackageName(),null));
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "جهت استفاده از برنامه دادن اجازه دسترسی ضروریست", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alert();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, final PermissionToken token) {
                        alert();
                    }
                }).check();

    }
    public void alert(){

        AlertDialog.Builder Hoshdar = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        Hoshdar.setTitle("توجه");
        Hoshdar.setMessage("جهت استفاده از برنامه دادن اجازه دسترسی ضروریست لطفا درقسمت تنظیمات اجازه دسترسی را فعال کنید");
        Hoshdar.setCancelable(false);
        Hoshdar.setPositiveButton("رفتن به تنظیمات", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package",getPackageName(),null));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Hoshdar.create().show();
    }

    public void fav_intent(View view) {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse).duration(600).playOn(btn_fav);
        mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Fehrest.class);
                intent.putExtra("button","fav");
                intent.putExtra("activity","main");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        },1500);
    }



    public void text_intent(View view) {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse).duration(600).playOn(btn_last_story);
        if (read){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent_movies = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Text_activity.class);
                    intent_movies.putExtra("activity","main");
                    startActivity(intent_movies);

                }
            },1500);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "هنوز هیچ داستانی مطالعه نکردید!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    public void setting_intent(MenuItem item) {
        mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse).duration(600).playOn(img_setting);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Setting.class));

            }
        },1500);

    }

    public void set_music(MenuItem item) {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.Pulse).duration(600).playOn(img_music);

        if (music){
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayMusic.class));
            img_music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music_off_icon);
            music=false;
            sharedP.edit().putBoolean(Items.MUSIC, false).apply();
        }else {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayMusic.class));
            img_music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music_on_icon);
            music=true;
            sharedP.edit().putBoolean(Items.MUSIC, true).apply();
        }
    }


    public void get_night(){

        music = sharedP.getBoolean(Items.MUSIC,true);
        night_mode = sharedP.getBoolean(Items.NIGHT_MODE,false);
        read = sharedP.getBoolean(Items.READ,false);

        if (night_mode){
            lin_main.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Black0);
            img_night.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sun_icon);
            img_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main2);

        }else {
            lin_main.setBackgroundResource(0);
            img_night.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.moon_icon);
            img_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main);
        }

        if (!music){
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayMusic.class));
            img_music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music_off_icon);
        }else {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayMusic.class));
            img_music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music_on_icon);
        }
    }
    public void set_night(View view){

        YoYo.with(Techniques.RotateIn).duration(800).playOn(img_night);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (night_mode){
                    lin_main.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    img_night.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.moon_icon);
                    img_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main);
                    sharedP.edit().putBoolean(Items.NIGHT_MODE, false).apply();
                    night_mode=false;

                }else {
                    lin_main.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Black0);
                    img_night.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sun_icon);
                    img_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main2);
                    sharedP.edit().putBoolean(Items.NIGHT_MODE, true).apply();
                    night_mode=true;
                }

            }
        },800);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        get_night();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayMusic.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void finish(View view) {
        mDrawer.closeMenu(true);
        finish();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void taptarget(){

        new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTarget(R.id.img_night)
                .setPrimaryText("فعال کردن حالت شب")
                .setSecondaryText("با زدن این دکمه میتوانید حالت مطالعه در شب را فعال یا غیر فعال کنید")
                //.setPrimaryTextColour(Color.parseColor("#13dc74"))
                // .setSecondaryTextColour(Color.parseColor("#13dc74"))
                .setFocalColour(R.color.mycolorGray)
                .setBackButtonDismissEnabled(false)
                .setBackgroundColour(Color.parseColor("#635B5B"))
                .setPromptStateChangeListener(new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.PromptStateChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPromptStateChanged(MaterialTapTargetPrompt prompt, int state)
                    {
                        if (state == MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_FOCAL_PRESSED|| state==MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_NON_FOCAL_PRESSED)
                        {
                            // User has pressed the prompt target
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "اولی", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            txt_target();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    private void txt_target(){
        new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTarget(R.id.img_icon)
                .setFocalColour(R.color.mycolorGray)
                .setPrimaryText("منوی کشویی")
                .setSecondaryText("با زدن این دکمه منوی کشویی برنامه باز خواهد شد که شامل آیتم های مختلفی می باشد")
                .setBackgroundColour(Color.parseColor("#635B5B"))
                .setPromptStateChangeListener(new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.PromptStateChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPromptStateChanged(MaterialTapTargetPrompt prompt, int state)
                    {
                        if (state == MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_FOCAL_PRESSED || state==MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_NON_FOCAL_PRESSED)
                        {
                            // User has pressed the prompt target
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "دومی", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            target3();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    private void target3(){
        new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTarget(R.id.img_music)

                .setPrimaryText("فعال/غیرفعال موزیک")
                .setSecondaryText("با زدن این دکمه میتوانید موزیک پس زمینه حین مطالعه را پخش یا قطع کنید")
                .setBackgroundColour(Color.parseColor("#635B5B"))
                .setPromptStateChangeListener(new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.PromptStateChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPromptStateChanged(MaterialTapTargetPrompt prompt, int state)
                    {
                        if (state == MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_FOCAL_PRESSED || state==MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_NON_FOCAL_PRESSED)
                        {
                            // User has pressed the prompt target
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "دومی", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            target4();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    private void target4(){
        new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTarget(R.id.img_setting)

                .setPrimaryText("تنظیمات")
                .setSecondaryText("با زدن این دکمه بخش تنظیمات باز خواهد شد که شامل تغییر فونت متن ، سایز متن و ... می باشد")
                .setBackgroundColour(Color.parseColor("#635B5B"))
                .setPromptStateChangeListener(new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.PromptStateChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPromptStateChanged(MaterialTapTargetPrompt prompt, int state)
                    {
                        if (state == MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_FOCAL_PRESSED || state==MaterialTapTargetPrompt.STATE_NON_FOCAL_PRESSED)
                        {
                            // User has pressed the prompt target
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "دومی", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sharedP.edit().putBoolean(Items.INTROPAGE, false).apply();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if (!(exit ==null)){
            super.onBackPressed();
            //MainActivity.this.finish();
        }else {
            exit = Toast.makeText(this,"برای خروج دوباره بزنید",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            exit.show();
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                exit= null;

            }
        },3000);
    }
}
```

this my main activity xml code:

[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 1]

[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 2]

[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 3]

[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 4]

[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 5]
[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 6]
[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 7]
[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 8]
[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 9]
[image: This is a photo of the main activity XML code part 10]
Splash Screen Activity Run enters Intro Page. After clicking the reject or complete button, the program will not enter the activity menu and the program will close.

Comment: You must find the view that setting it's alpha and check why is it null. or post your main activity cods

Comment: Check your findViewByIds that has right id name

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible. I edited the text, took photos of our code, and left it. Thank you for your guidance